# Writing data to the file

Tags: python, input, output

Question: *Write a function schrijfKwadraten(naam, N) to the file with specified name per line, writing an integer, namely the squares 0 t.e.m. N**2 *

```
def schrijfKwadraten(text, N):
    with open(text, 'w') as f:
        for i in range(0, N+1):
            f.write('%d'%(i*i))
```

I tried editing the code multiple times. Nothing works.  The code below gives the correct list, for N = 10

```
print('%d'%(i*i))
0
1
4
9
16
25
36
49
64
81
100
```

When I use, `f.write()` . Python gives me a list of numbers, when I take N = 10. This is wrong, since 10*10 = 100, not 3!

```
1 
1 
1 
1 
2 
2 
2 
2 
2 
2 
3
```

Control coding,  gives me error:

```
schrijfKwadraten('TestKwadraten.txt', 10)

with open('TestKwadraten.txt', 'r') as infile:
    l = [int(i) for i in infile]
assert l == [i*i for i in range(11)],'Fout in schrijfKwadraten()'
print('Correct !')
```

Can anyone help me out? Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the wrong solution it gives you? What should be the right solution?

Comment: At first glance you probably should separate the numbers in the file: `f.write('%d ' % (i * i))` (space after d)

Comment: Maybe what you are looking for is `open(text, 'w').writelines([str(i ** 2) for i in range(0, N + 1)])`?

Comment: Format output code properly,put space on newline after each digits. Please,put sample output also and what it should look like.

Comment: Please look at [ask] and provide a [mcve]. We cannot help you unless we know what `text` is and what your actual and expected output is, along with any errors you might have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code works perfectly for me in Python 3. But to get the desired output I had to add a linebreak '\n'. It is also preferable to use the string.format() syntax as seen below.

```
def schrijfKwadraten(text, N):
    with open(text, 'w') as f:
        for i in range(0, N+1):
            f.write('{}\n'.format(i**2))
            #f.write('%d\n'%(i*i))


schrijfKwadraten("hello.txt", 10)
```

Comment: Thank you!  I added those 2 elements in my code and it works now!

Comment: Glad it worked! Consider marking this as an answer if it solved your problem.